# How to add google analytics to jhipster production?

Tags: google-analytics, jhipster

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Bx8BU3wxaA&t=378s

When I run **npm start** it seems to be working fine but when I build the production file or run **./gradlew** then it does not work anymore. No errors or anything.

Any ideas why?

To reproduce just generate new jhipster app & modify 2 files:

**Modified files:**

```
\src\main\webapp\index.html
```

```
    ...
    <!-- jhipster-needle-add-resources-to-root - JHipster will add new resources here -->
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-*******-1"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());        
    </script>
</head>
```

```
src\main\webapp\app\layouts\main\main.component.ts
```

```
  import { *** } from '***';
  declare let gtag: any;
  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.updateTitle();
        gtag('config', 'UA-******-1', {'page_path':event.urlAfterRedirects});   <--
      }
      ...
```

Comment: No errors in browser's console?